# http-equiv and set inverval not synchronous

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, refresh

**Context :**

I am working on an asp.net project which is a slideshow using an ASPX page as slide page.

This page programmatically add all images on an  tag during the pageload of the codebehind, then all images are sliding thanks to a SetInterval Jquery function.

To add a new image to the slide, we use a form (in another page of the site).

In order to display new images when they are published with the form, i want the slide page to refresh at the end of the loop.

**What i did :**

I set the **interval as 15000** (15 seconds) in the Jquery function. To refresh the page, i used the **http-equiv="refresh"** attribute of the meta tag.

As i want the page to be refreshed at the end of the setInterval loop, i set the Refresh parameter (in codebehind) at **RefreshTimer = 15 * ImageNumber.**

So, if i have 3 images, my page should refresh every 45 secondes, with 15 seconds display for each.

**What is wrong :**

I notice that this is not working fine. The page doesn't refresh at the very end of the last image.

When the loop ends, the 1st image is displayed again for about 0.5s ~ 1s, then the refresh occurs.

**Question :**

Do you have an idea what is wrong in this process. Why the page doesn't refresh at the good time ?
Here are some code element :

Jquery function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $(".slide div:first-child").css({ marginTop: function (index) {
                        $(".slide div:first-child").css({ marginTop: 0 }).appendTo(".slide");
                        return index;
                        }
                    });
                verticalAlignCenter();
                }, 15000);
            }); });
```

Thanx for any advice

Comment: Well, i can solve this by setting the refresh timer as : Refreshtimer = 15 * ImageNumber -1, but this is a mcGyver fix

Comment: I was able to fix it by using a setinterval + location.reload().
So, does the problem occurs because http-evuiv refresh and setinterval have not the same starting point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function to reload my page :

```
setInterval(function () {
                    location.reload();
                }, $("#<%=refreshTime.ClientID%>").val());
```

$("#<%=refreshTime.ClientID%>").val() is simply a way to get a value from code behind page load.

I think my problem occurred because there should be delay between when the page starts to count (http-equiv="refresh") and when above function starts.